# 2 DIVS are overlapping with zoom effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a practice website with Bootstrap 4 (this is my first time using it). I've come up with a problem in the layout that I'm designing  and its probably something really simple but I cant work it out.

```
<div id="box-container" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="box-row" class="row">
        <div id="header-box1" class="col-lg-6 header-box">
        </div>
        <div id="header-box2" class="col-lg-6 header-box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Full demo](https://output.jsbin.com/gupavozaha) | [Full code](https://jsbin.com/gupavozaha/edit?html,css,output) (ignore the images, they're all just placeholder)

View the full demo and you'll notice that I have 2 boxes which I have placed a zoom hover effect on. The left box is working exactly how it should be, however the right one is overlapping the left. I know this is something simple but I just cant wrap my head around it.

Any advice?
Cheers

Comment: Set the `z-index` to 1 for both and on hover make it 2.

Comment: @OfficialAntarctica It didn't work :(

Comment: Copy the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/42262836/3798034, tested it and it works.

Comment: Try changing the markup to `<div class="col-lg-6"><div id="header-box1" class="header-box"></div></div><div class="col-lg-6"><div id="header-box2" class="header-box"></div></div>` and add `height: 100%;` to `.header-box` and `overflow: hidden;` to `#box-row .col-lg-6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for modifying the background-size.

```
.header-box {
    background-position: center;
    background-size:100%;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.header-box:hover{
    background-size:150%;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE6 and 7 */ 
}
```

Comment: OP said that doesn't work. And they don't want the element to appear over the other when it scales, and a higher z-index on hover would make it appear over the other element.

Comment: I tried copying your exact code and it was still the same for me.

Comment: @jkarakizi Ok, I misunderstood what you wanted - try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Move the divs with the backgrounds into your bootstrap col elements, set `overflow: hidden;` on the bootstrap cols, then set the box elements to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;`

```css
#header-box1 {
  background-image: url(http://indianapublicmedia.org/arts/files/2012/04/sample-gates-9-940x626.jpg);
}

#header-box2 {
  background-image: url(http://indianapublicmedia.org/arts/files/2012/04/sample-gates-9-940x626.jpg);
}

#box-row {
  height: 250px; /* you don't need to modify this */
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-box {
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.header-box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand');
}

#box-row > .col-lg-6 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="box-container" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="box-row" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="header-box1" class="header-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="header-box2" class="header-box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the Div of each image in another div of their own, and set overflow to none. make sure the z-index of the outer div is higher.